Tengo un df con numeros enteros y decimales. Los decimales los lee como caracteres. Ya he probado la función double, as.numeric y me da error
data_normalized <- scale(numerical_data)
Error en colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE): 'x' debe ser numérico

Tengo un df del cual quiero hacer un PCA y no puedo normalizar los datos. 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  31 variables:
$ Recuento.de.Hongos         : int  56 59
$ Relación.Hongos.Bacterias  : chr  "17,36" "10,31"
$ Talaromyces.principal.Hongo: int  31 29
$ Recuento.de.Bacterias      : int  972 608
$ Proteobacterias            : int  41 48
$ alpha.Proteobacterias      : int  22 30
$ beta.Proteobacterias       : chr  "4,07" "4,66"

¡Bienvenido @Franco Farias! Para poder ayudarte es necesario tener más información sobre los datos que has cargado. ¿Cómo has cargado los datos en R y qué aspecto tienen (mira lo que obtienes con la función dput() incluyendo dentro el nombre de tu tabla

El problema se debe a que tus valores numéricos tinen coma (,) como separador decimal en lugar de punto (.), eso provoca que el número sea interpretado como character y al hacer la coerción a numérico se genera un NA. Esto se puede resolver de dos maneras: con la fuerza bruta o de una forma más sutil.
Método de fuerza bruta: ubica las ,, las sustituye por . y luego hacer la coerción a numérico.
numerical_data <- sapply(numerical_data, \(x) as.numeric(sub(",", "\\.", x)))
scale(numerical_data)

Método sutil: Este consistiría en remediar el problema desde el momento de la importación de los datos fijando el argumento dec = "," para que R entienda que las comas son los separadores decimales, así, ya sea que hayas usando read.csv o read.table debes hacer lo siguiente:
read.table(..., dec = ",")
read.csv(..., dec = ",")

